# C# error with creating fixed size Vector3 array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working with C# for the first time and trying to create an array of `Vector3` with the following code:

```
public Vector3[] an_array;
void Start() {
    an_array = new Vector3[height.Length * height.Length];  //Line 47
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
WaterWakeTutorial.Start () (at Assets/WaterWakeTutorial.cs:47)
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does `an_array = new Vector3[10];` work for example? If yes, the problem is with the `height.Length` expression. Do you know how to use the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

height is null. The NullReferenceException occurs when you are trying to access one if it's members, i.e. Length.